# C check before writing to closed pipe

Tags: c, pipe

Is there an easy way to check if a pipe is closed before writing to it in C? I have a child and parent process, and the parent has a pipe to write to the child. However, if the child closes the pipe and the parent tries to read - I get a broken pipe error.

So how can I check to make sure I can write to the pipe, so I can handle it as an error if I can't? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple way to check would be to do a 0 byte write(2) to the pipe and check the return.  If you're catching SIGPIPE or checking for EPIPE, you get the error.  But that's just the same as if you go ahead and do your real write, checking for the error return.  So, just do the write and handle an error either in a signal handler (SIGPIPE) or, if the signal is ignored, by checking the error return from write.

Comment: Doing a **write(2)** with byte count set to 0 can't detect broken pipe, most implementations would simply return 0 to indicate that 0 bytes has been successfully written.

Answer (score 4):

How about just try to write and deal with the error? The same way you would for a write to a file or a database. I see no value in the idiom:

```
check if *this* is going to work
do *this*
```

You merely introduce a smaller, and harder to catch in testing, window of opportunity:

```
check if *this* is going to work
   child thinks "Ha, fooled you, I'm off now!"
do *this*, which now fails!
```

Comment: No this actually has legitimate use. Consider a parent process checking if its child died because the socket it passed to it was closed by the peer. Also the idiom you are referring to is called "Look before you leap".

Comment: @matt, what value is the check first adding? The write can still fail even if the child was initially healthy. Can the parent infer some extra information from the check. Is it guaranteed that if an initial check fails it's for the reason you say rather than the child died for some other reason. My thought was that all we actually know is that the child is not there when we want it to be and hence we detect that by write working or not.